# How to ease support for cross-compilation with autoconf

Tags: configuration, autoconf

I maintain a package auto configuration that uses `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` to look for libraries my code depends on. I would like to make it easy for people aiming at cross-compiling my package: The main problem of `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` being that it gets BUILD system information and not HOST.

My approach is the following: I do not use a rootfs of the HOST system, but compile each packages my package depends on separately. Then, I would like to be able to force the values of `DEPENDSON_LIBS` or `DEPENDSON_CFLAGS` when calling the `./configure` srcipt. Is this a good approach? How can configure.in be written to allow this?

NOTE: I tried `AC_ARG_VAR`  without success...

Answer (score 1):

`PKG_CHECK_MODULES` first checks if `host-prefix-pkg-config` exists, and then fallbacks to unprefixed `pkg-config` (which may give confusing result).

I'm not sure if I understand your approach (the second paragraph), but anyway I'd leave setting correct paths to the user. You may add `AC_CHECK_LIB` after `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` to check if the picked library is for the same system as compiler.

The user who is cross-compiling may have `host-prefix-pkg-config` already installed, for example some linux distros have it packaged in addition to MinGW cross-compiler.
If not, it's enough to set proper env. variables. Autotools Mythbuster recommends a [wrapper that sets these variables](http://www.flameeyes.eu/autotools-mythbuster/pkgconfig/cross-compiling.html).

As a last resort, the user can directly set `*_CFLAGS` and `*_LIBS`.